# How to adjust the scale/axes of networkx points overlayed onto an image using matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

I'm trying to overlay the cities and tour of the gr120 Travelling Salesman Problem above a map of Germany.

I need help figuring out how I can resize the axes or scale the plots of G such that they somewhat align with the map of Germany (since they aren't proper coordinates this will be approximate).

Things I've tried: two axes, tight layout. None with any success but I'm also a little new to matplotlib.

Here is my code. The package tsplib95 allows for importing TSP instances and converting them to networkx graphs easily.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import image
import networkx as nx
import tsplib95 # pip install tsplib95

problem = tsplib95.load('gr120.tsp')
problem_dict = problem.as_dict()

cities = problem_dict["dimension"]

G = problem.get_graph() # Converts .tsp file to nx graph G
pos = problem.display_data # get 'coordinates' of cities (values range from 8 to 159 for x and 12 to 258 y-coordinates)

fig,ax = plt.subplots()

#image:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Module:Location_map/data/Germany#/media/File:Relief_Map_of_Germany.svg
data = image.imread('de.png') # Can this be resized? How to get the axis dimensions from this?
implot = ax.imshow(data)

nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos=pos, node_size = cities/10) # draw nodes
# tour variable is of form [1,3,4,2,1] --> edgelist is [(1,3),(3,4),(4,2),(2,1)]
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos=pos, edgelist=tour_to_edgelist(tour), edge_color='red') # edges in the path

plt.show()
```

[image: This is the result right now]

but this is what it should look like:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options:

1. To set the dimensions of the image when you use it in the plot, use the `extent` argument of `ax.imshow()` like the following:

```
ax.imshow(data, extent=[0, 170, 0, 270])
```

2. You could find the dimensions of your original image with `.shape` method (`data.shape` returns a tuple with dimensions in this case) and then rescale your graph positions using one of either [`nx.rescale_layout()`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.layout.rescale_layout.html) or [`nx.rescale_layout_dict()`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.layout.rescale_layout_dict.html).  You may need to adjust the x,y-center of your graph position as well.  This method is more complicated, but you get to stick to your original image scale.